# AndroidJUnit4 test passes in debug, fails to start in run

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am facing an issue with unit tests for my activity in JUnit4. The app is a game so the main playing activity is rather complicated. I want to test that once started and unpaused (it starts in pause mode by default) the game runs for 5 secs without crashing. I consider this a passing run.

The `onCreate` of the activity does some relatively heavy lifting in separate threads and I need to wait with unpausing until it's done. The code below illustrates the test case.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class GameTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<GameActivity> mActivityRule =
                new ActivityTestRule<>(GameActivity.class, true, false);

    @Before
    public void launchActivity() throws Throwable {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        /* ... skipped building intent ... */
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);

        // wait till the constructors finish
        while (!mActivityRule.getActivity().gameLoopStarted) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void gameRunsFor5sec() throws Throwable {
        mActivityRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // unpause
                mActivityRule.getActivity().playPause(null);
            }
        });            

        Time t = Time.getCurrent();
        // wait 5 secs before considering the test passed
        while (Time.getCurrent().since(t).getMillis() < 5000) { }
    }
}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that the test always passes in `debug` mode of the Android Studio, and fails to properly start in `run` mode; in `debug` it takes some 100-200ms for the activity to load (the Thread.sleep loop), the game gets unpaused and after 5sec the test finishes. In `run` the game gets loaded same as in `debug`, but then unpausing just doesn't happen and the test times out after 45sec. The activity is otherwise fully functional, one can manually unpause the game on the emulator and play, for example. I have previously tried different approaches, like waiting static 5 sec instead of checking the gameLoopStarted flag, but the results were the same.